Android TitleBar will not go away after upgrading from Flutter 3.16.5 to 3.24.1
We recently upgraded our Flutter app to 3.24.1 and noticed that our Android app now persistently shows the ToolBar, seemingly no matter what I do to the app's theme to address this. We know it's the Android ToolBar and not Flutter's AppBar as this doesn't happen in iOS:
Current styles.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#804EFD</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/NormalTheme</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_splash_layer</item>
    </style>
</resources>


Application tag in AndroidManifest.xml:
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="App name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">

Activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml:
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"       
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

class MainActivity : FlutterFragmentActivity() {

    private var methodChannelResult: MethodChannel.Result? = null

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(
            flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
            CHANNEL
        ).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            this.methodChannelResult = result
        }
    }
}

This setup has actually been untouched for a long, long time but this release seems to want something else beyond extending a theme labelled as NoTitleBar.
Screenshot:

What have I tried?

Including the following in my styles.xml and values-night/styles.xml:

<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

Lots of answers out there suggest fullscreen but not only does this not work; I don't want to hide the status bar in pursuit of the desired outcome. I tried the above in full and in part across LaunchTheme, NormalTheme and Theme.App.Starting.

Adding the following code to MainActivity.kt:

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    this.window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
}

This feels like overkill (what's all the XML theming for if you have to make calls in code anyway?) and it throws an error about having to call requestFeature() (the method I'm actually calling) before adding content.
I'd love to know:

Why this is happening
What changes I need to make to remove the ToolBar

If this change is documented somewhere and I'm just being a dummy, feel free to downvote

The fix for this was to explicitly reference the normal theme in my AndroidManifest.xml:

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
        android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

    <!-- Rest of your Manifest's application stuff-->
</application>


This'll happen for new projects by default, as evidenced by a new build flavour for my app already having this in place.
There's a migration guide alluding to this here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/docs/platforms/android/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects.md
